# ModX контроль доступа, предоставить доступ к приложениям

Tags: modx, revo, настройка, доступ, админка

Добрый день, настраивал Контроль Доступа на ModX и столкнулся с такой проблемой, что в аккаунте менеджера отсутствует меню "Приложения"- а именно мне оттуда нужна Галерея, чтобы менеджер мог создавать альбомы, редактировать, добавлять итп
[image: Нужен пункт Gallery, сниппета Gallery]
Где в настройках это добавить, уже весь контроль вдоль и поперек прошел, а найти не могу

Спасибо

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте сделать следующее:

1. Нажмите на шестеренку в верхнем правом углу и выберите пункт "Контроль доступа"
2. На открывшейся странице выберите вкладку "Политики доступа". В появившемся списке политик выберите ту, которая соответствует вашему менеджеру. Кликните по этой строке правой кнопкой мыши и выберите в появившемся контекстном меню пункт "Редактировать".

[image: контроль доступа]

3. На открывшейся странице найдите строку `components "Видеть меню Компоненты"`, отметьте ее галочкой и нажмите кнопку "Сохранить" в верху страницы.
4. Перегрузите права доступа, воспользовавшись пунктом меню `Управление - Перезагрузить права доступа`

Comment: Спасибо большое, пришлось откатить хостинг, как заново все проделаю, проверю )